# node-supervisor not starting my node server

Tags: node.js, node-supervisor

If I run (from within my project dir):

```
supervisor javascripts/index.js
```

I get:
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory

If I run:

```
node javascripts/index.js
```

It starts up my server properly.

Does anyone know what I may be doing wrong, or understand what this error message is trying to tell me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. Apparently node-supervisor is looking for node under "node" but it is installed under "nodejs"

```
ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

Command from here: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/3911

Fixed it.